# ffmpeg: extract frames and get their exact timestamps

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, extract

I'm trying to extract frames from a **variable framerate** video every 5 seconds and get the exact timestamps of each frame extracted. This is what I have so so far:

```
-i inputfile -vstats_file vstats.log  -vsync 2 -vcodec png -r 0.2 -f image2pipe -
```

And this is what I get:

```
frame=     1 q= 0.0 f_size= 136261 s_size=      133kB **time= 5.000** br=   218.0kbits/s avg_br=   218.0kbits/s type= I
frame=     2 q= 0.0 f_size= 139382 s_size=      269kB **time= 10.000** br=   223.0kbits/s avg_br=   220.5kbits/s type= I
frame=     3 q= 0.0 f_size= 141631 s_size=      407kB **time= 15.000** br=   226.6kbits/s avg_br=   222.5kbits/s type= I
```

I need the exact timestamp of the frame that was used for extraction, so I can later accurately cut the video based on thumbnails generated.

Also, is there a way to print vstats to stdout rather than a file?

Comment: non-ffmpeg solutions are fine too, as long as it's a command-line tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'm not sure what you tried to do, but if it works for you then it's ok...

Anyway, for skipping frames I would have use [SELECT](http://ffmpeg.org/libavfilter.html#select) video filter (make sure you have libavfilter enable).
For frames infoI would have used [SHOWINFO](http://ffmpeg.org/libavfilter.html#toc-showinfo) video filter.

Your command should be something like the following:

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile -vf '[in]select=not(mod(n\,150))[s1];[s1]showinfo[out]' -vcodec mpeg2video outputfile
```

(where 150 frames are 5sec * 30fps)

Comment: showinfo is exactly what I needed, thanks. By the way, for a variable framerate video I used `select='isnan(prev_selected_t)+gte(t-prev_selected_t,5)'` to get a frame every 5 seconds.

Comment: @Mango 'isnan(prev_selected_t)+gte(t-prev_selected_t,5)' this filter does not work for me, is it still valid?